# Question regarding decimal arithmetic

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, datatypes, decimal

I think my understanding of precision vs scale might be incorrect as the following example produces values that do not make sense to me. `decimal(32, 14)` rounds the result to 6 decimal places, while the `decimal(18, 14)` rounds to 19. My understanding of decimal is `decimal(p, [s])`, where `p` is the total number of digits and `s` is the number of digits after the decimal (i.g., `decimal(10, 2)` would result in 8 digits to the left of the decimal and 2 digits to the right). Is this not correct?

I created a small example that illustrates the seemingly odd behavior:

```
--------------------
-- Truncates at pipe
-- 1.043686|655...
--------------------
declare @dVal1 decimal(32, 14) = 10
declare @dVal2 decimal(32, 14) = 9.581419815465469

select @dVal1 Val1, @dVal2 Val2, @dVal1 / @dVal2 CalcResult

----------------
-- Most accurate
----------------
declare @dVal3 decimal(18, 14) = 10
declare @dVal4 decimal(18, 14) = 9.581419815465469

select @dVal3 Val3, @dVal4 Val4, @dVal3 / @dVal4 CalcResult
```

So on to the question, what is it that I am missing to understand this? The articles and msdn blogs I have read don't seem to provide clarity (at least to my thought process). Can someone explain to me why a higher precision seems to result in a loss of scale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is correct though you have 1 too many digits for `@dVal2` and `@dVal4` which is why you see these being rounded up to 7 (`9.58141981546547`) for the last digit in your `select`

As for the division rounding, it's hidden in the [middle of the docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> In multiplication and division operations we need precision - scale
>   places to store the integral part of the result. The scale might be
>   reduced using the following rules:
>
> The resulting scale is reduced to min(scale, 38 – (precision-scale))
>   if the integral part is less than 32, because it cannot be greater
>   than 38 – (precision-scale). Result might be rounded in this case.
>
> The
>   scale will not be changed if it is less than 6 and if the integral
>   part is greater than 32. In this case, overflow error might be raised
>   if it cannot fit into decimal(38, scale)
>
> The scale will be set to 6 if
>   it is greater than 6 and if the integral part is greater than 32. In
>   this case, both integral part and scale would be reduced and resulting
>   type is decimal(38,6). Result might be rounded to 6 decimal places or
>   overflow error will be thrown if integral part cannot fit into 32
>   digits.

So in your first case `decimal(32,14)`, the scale is being set to 6 digits because the resulting value `decimal(64,28)` has a `scale = 28` which is > 6 and the integral part `(64-28) = 36` is > 32 as defined in the last rule above. Thus, `decimal(38,6)`

In your second case `decimal(18,14)`, the first rule is being applied for your scale for the resulting value of `decimal(36,28)` to `min(28, 38 -(36-28)) = min(28,30) = 28`. Thus, `decimal(38,28)`

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. I didnt see the 3 additional conditions down there on that doc, thanks for pointing that out! A follow up question, how did you determine the new precision/scale of 64,28? That doesnt appear to follow the rules on the doc you linked.

Working it out myself based on the doc, I came to the precision of 51 and the scale of 47. Am I doing something goofy in my math?
    precision = 32 - 14 + 14 + max(6, 32 + 14 + 1) = 32 - 28 + 47 = 51
    scale = max(6, 32 + 14 + 1) = 47

Comment: I think I goofed it up actually @Mythikos

Comment: ahh alright. Regardless, thank you for the help!